# Android Alarm Style CheckBox with Text

Tags: android, checkbox, android-drawable, android-styles, android-checkbox

How do I create a ToggleButton's below the repeat checkbox (Mon, Tue, Wed etc) in the Clock application? I'm thinking its a styled ToggleButton?

[image: Clock Toggle Buttons?]

Comment: Yes its a default ToggleButton : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ToggleButton.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a few nine patch drawables and a custom selector drawable. 
The source can be found here:
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/DeskClock/+/master/res/

Notable files:

drawable/toggle_underline.xml

drawable-XXXX/toggle_underline_activated.9.png

drawable-XXXX/toggle_underline_normal.9.png

layout/day-button.xml

Answer (score 0):

No this is the default toggleButton.

Comment: The default ToogleButton looks like this http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/togglebutton.html correct?